# Call is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, call, jquery-callback

I'm trying to set up my plugin to accept a callback function inside as a option argument:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.MyjQueryPlugin = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            onEnd: function(e) {}
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            // do stuff (complete() gets called here)

        });
    };

    function complete(e){
        settings.onEnd.call(this); // <- the error?
    }

})(jQuery);
```

But I get a error that call() is undefined. What's wrong with my code?

ok, I changed this with:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.MyjQueryPlugin = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            onEnd: function(e) {}
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        var complete = function(e){
          settings.onEnd.call(this); // <- the error?
        }


        return this.each(function() {
            // do stuff (complete() gets called here)

        });
    };   

})(jQuery);
```

and the error is still there...

Comment: It would be useful to quote the error in your question.

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/pwF5k/).

Comment: yes it does, the problem was in another function that uses call() and forgot to change it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to reference `settings` outside of the function in which it's defined. You've scoped `settings` to be a local variable within the function you assign to `$.fn.MyjQueryPlugin`, but then you're using it from a function that doesn't close over that local variable.

You *could* create a new `complete` function for every call to `MyjQueryPlugin` that closes over `settings`:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.MyjQueryPlugin = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            onEnd: function(e) {}
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            // do stuff (complete() gets called here)

        });

        // `complete` now closes over `settings`
        function complete(e){
            settings.onEnd.call(this); // <- the error?
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

...but of course that involves creating a function. Maybe that's fine, depends on what the plug-in does.

Alternately, pass `settings` into `complete` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

`settings` is not in scope inside of `complete()`.

Comment: *"You would need to do var settings just inside of your self invoking function.*" If he does that, the same `settings` will be shared by all calls to `MyjQueryPlugin`, which probably isn't what's needed given that it's mixing the `options` argument into `settings`.

Comment: @T.J. They should be overwritten on each new call to the plugin wouldn't they? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/wk5ps/). BTW, the OP is a *she* :)

Comment: (lower case 'a'): We don't know the calls aren't overlapping (ajax, `setTimeout`, etc). @Alex (with the capital 'A'): Sorry about that!

Comment: @T.J. I see what you mean. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/zVQg4/). I'll edit my answer to be correct and brief :)

Answer (score 1):

the variable settings is out of scope in the complete function. Place the complete function in the function where you have defined settings.

```
$.fn.MyjQueryPlugin = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        onEnd: function(e) {}
    };

    function complete(e){
        settings.onEnd.call(this); // <- the error?
    }

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        // do stuff (complete() gets called here)

    });
};
```